# How does "hold action" work in EABA?

Tags: combat, readied-action, initiative, eaba

For EABA ("End All Be All" game system), you can "hold action" ([page 8 of the quickstart rules](https://www.btrc.net/images/stories/freedownloads/eabav2/EABAv201_quickstart_flat.pdf#page=9)) to act preemptively to a specific trigger (e.g. shoot if they try to shoot).

- How much can you describe for a held action? Can you say "aim and then shoot if they try to shoot", or is aiming (+2 time) not "simple" or "fast" enough?
- How much can you describe for a trigger? Is it acceptable to say "if A shoots B or C then shoot A first, but don't shoot if A attacks anyone else"? Or "shoot A if they do anything"?
- What happens to your turn if the specific thing did not happen? Is it wasted? Which seems unreasonable for those turns that end up being minutes long. Or do you just get moved to the bottom of the initiative order for that round?
- When do you get the +2 initiative bonus? Would this be at the start of the next round after the round you took the hold action? And only if the the trigger did not occur?